# MariaDB Galera Cluster - nodes fail to start

Tags: replication, mariadb, mysql-cluster, galera

This is a new installation (fresh VM and MariaDB install). For some reason, the nodes are having  trouble joining the master server. The master server would pause at `Preparing binlog files for transfer` while this would result as a `Starting MariaDB database server mysqld [fail]` on the nodes.

**Log from node-1** (hostname: vvalu_china_1)

```
azureuser@cv-server1:~$ sudo service mysql start
 * Starting MariaDB database server mysqld                                     [fail]
azureuser@cv-server1:~$ tail -f /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
141031  10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
141031  10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 5 (3, 1)
141031  10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
141031  10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 0, protocol version: 3
141031  10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
141031  10:12:10 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to prepare for incremental state transfer: Local state UUID (3c2b4e20-60a3-11e4-a3f2-4252be4415e1) does not match group state UUID (20156cae-60a2-11e4-b7d8-0abd6e366161): 1 (Operation not permitted)
         at galera/src/replicator_str.cpp:prepare_for_IST():447. IST will be unavailable.
141031  10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: Member 1.0 (vvalu_china_1) requested state transfer from '*any*'. Selected 0.0 (vvalu_master_local)(SYNCED) as donor.
141031  10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: Shifting PRIMARY -> JOINER (TO: 0)
141031  10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: Requesting state transfer: success, donor: 0
```

**Log from primary** (hostname: vvalu_master_local)

```
141031 10:11:50 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
141031 10:11:50 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.0.14-MariaDB-1~trusty-wsrep-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution, wsrep_25.10.r4144
141031 10:11:50 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
141031 10:11:50 [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 5 (3, 1)
141031 10:11:50 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
141031 10:11:50 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 0, protocol version: 3
141031 10:11:50 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
141031 10:11:50 [Note] WSREP: Synchronized with group, ready for connections
141031 10:11:50 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
141031 10:12:09 [Note] WSREP: declaring 516e8fc1-60a3-11e4-8fc0-3bde09ed89e0 stable
141031 10:12:09 [Note] WSREP: Node 467a1d82-60a3-11e4-8419-420e1bb83a75 state prim
141031 10:12:09 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(PRIM,467a1d82-60a3-11e4-8419-420e1bb83a75,2) memb {
        467a1d82-60a3-11e4-8419-420e1bb83a75,0
        516e8fc1-60a3-11e4-8fc0-3bde09ed89e0,0
} joined {
} left {
} partitioned {
})
141031 10:12:09 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 0, memb_num = 2
141031 10:12:09 [Note] WSREP: STATE_EXCHANGE: sent state UUID: 51d731ef-60a3-11e4-8ecd-5a0f37b3d4ad
141031 10:12:09 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: 51d731ef-60a3-11e4-8ecd-5a0f37b3d4ad
141031 10:12:09 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 51d731ef-60a3-11e4-8ecd-5a0f37b3d4ad from 0 (vvalu_master_local)
141031 10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 51d731ef-60a3-11e4-8ecd-5a0f37b3d4ad from 1 (vvalu_china_1)
141031 10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
        version    = 3,
        component  = PRIMARY,
        conf_id    = 1,
        members    = 1/2 (joined/total),
        act_id     = 0,
        last_appl. = 0,
        protocols  = 0/5/3 (gcs/repl/appl),
        group UUID = 20156cae-60a2-11e4-b7d8-0abd6e366161
141031 10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [23, 23]
141031 10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: 20156cae-60a2-11e4-b7d8-0abd6e366161:0, view# 2: Primary, number of nodes: 2, my index: 0, protocol version 3
141031 10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
141031 10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 5 (3, 1)
141031 10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
141031 10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 0, protocol version: 3
141031 10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
141031 10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: Member 1.0 (vvalu_china_1) requested state transfer from '*any*'. Selected 0.0 (vvalu_master_local)(SYNCED) as donor.
141031 10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: Shifting SYNCED -> DONOR/DESYNCED (TO: 0)
141031 10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
141031 10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: Running: 'wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'donor' --address '30.30.30.30:4444/rsync_sst' --auth '(null)' --socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --defaults-file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf'  --binlog '/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin' --gtid '20156cae-60a2-11e4-b7d8-0abd6e366161:0''
141031 10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: sst_donor_thread signaled with 0
141031 10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: Flushing tables for SST...
141031 10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: Provider paused at 20156cae-60a2-11e4-b7d8-0abd6e366161:0 (5)
141031 10:12:10 [Note] WSREP: Tables flushed.
WSREP_SST: [INFO] Preparing binlog files for transfer: (20141031 10:12:10.533)
mariadb-bin.000024
```

After ~10 mins, the master server would time out and here is the remaining log: http://pastebin.com/jayQmN43

And finally, here is the **config file** from the primary server:

```
[mysqld]
#mysql settings
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0

#galera settings
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name="vvalu_replicator"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://10.10.10.10,20.20.20.20,30.30.30.30"
wsrep_sst_method=rsync

wsrep_node_address="10.10.10.10"
wsrep_node_name="vvalu_master_local"
```

Note: OS - Ubuntu 14.04 x64/ MariaDB 10.0 Series

Answer (score -3):

I think you should switch back to Maria DB 5.5 for Galera support.

Comment: Galera is fully supported in MariaDB 10.